# How to keep home dynamic ip updated in laptop's hosts file, both linux

Tags: python, linux, networking, dhcp

I can script and program if necessary, but just looking for the best way to do this. What I have in mind is everytime I connect to my home network, I use NetworkManager, it would update the ip. That won't ensure 100% garuntee that it'll work, but it should be good enough.

If I did want 100% I was thinking I could have my desktop, an openSuse 11.4 box (somehow) run a script whenever the address gets changed and update it to a remote server which I have control of. Then as a fallback I can always just check that and manually change it.

Is there a better way than this though, seems like a good bit of work.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on "update the ip"?  A specific example would be helpful.  I can't tell if you mean your local ip or the router's ip.

Comment: Why don't You configure Your dhcp server?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to get a name on something like [dyndns](http://www.dyndns.com/) and use the name

Have you checked how often the IP actually changes? On most cable supplies it almost never does - minehas been the same for more than a year

Answer (score 0):

Googling [dynamic DNS](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=dynamic+dns&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=) will bring up a bunch of providers that do exactly this, both paid and free.  These providers will provide you a hostname that's tracked to your home's dynamic IP.  Some routers (e.g. WRT54G) include functionality to directly update the servers.